# Is a custom join(not through primary key) possible through Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can join Pair RDD's just fine through their primary keys, but is it possible to join based on certain attributes of the value object?

For example, lets say I have a List, or Pair List of two objects.

```
TV_station_information
    String station_name
    String call_sign


View_information
    String timeBlock
    String station_name
    int number_of_viewers
```

I'd like to join these two lists where the TV_station_information station_name matches the View_information station_name.

I can't make the key of View_information station_name, as each station has a ton of timeblocks. Also, I'm joining the View_information table across other tables as well through Spark.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: spark-java is a different project unrelated to apache-spark.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark needs to shuffle items with the same key to the same partition you need to have the key available as the first element of the Tuple in the PairRDD. For your example, probably the simplest thing to do is transform your RDDs to have the same primary key and keep the entire case class a the value. If your curious CoGroupedRDD.scala has some of the implementation specifics.

Comment: Duplicate keys are totally supported :)